# I need to delete words from text file in Slovak language

Tags: awk, words

I have text file in Slovak language:

```
SLOVESÁ
Sloveso, infinitív, obojvidové, afirmácia: abandonovať /VIj+
Sloveso, infinitív, obojvidové, negácia: abandonovať, neabandonovať /VIj-
Sloveso, prézent, obojvidové, singulár, 1. osoba, všeobecný rod, afirmácia: abandonovať, abandonujem /VKjsah+
Sloveso, prézent, obojvidové, singulár, 2. osoba, všeobecný rod, afirmácia: abandonovať, abandonuješ /VKjsbh+
Sloveso, prézent, obojvidové, singulár, 3. osoba, mužský rod, afirmácia: abandonovať, abandonuje /VKjscm+
```

And I need delete all words in every row until ":" and then everything after "/" (including ":", "/" and all first row).
Can somebody help me? What is best for me to use? AWK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU grep you can do:

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=: ).*(?= /)" inputfile
abandonovať
abandonovať, neabandonovať
abandonovať, abandonujem
abandonovať, abandonuješ
abandonovať, abandonuje
```

Comment: It works, Thank you. And I have one more little question. If I enter command grep -oP "(?<=: ).*(?= /)" inputfile > outputfile, than everything in the output file is in one row. And i want that it will be like in input file(max 2 words at line).

Comment: Shouldn't be in one row (isn't for me here).  Are you using Windows to check the file?

Comment: Yea, I'm using windows. Output in cmd is like in your post but if I enter command with "> outputfile" at the end, in outputfile is everything in a one row.

Comment: Then your output file is probably in Unix format, which has different line separators.  Do `unix2dos outputfile` and you'll have a file with the correct line separators.